# gRPC: Issue when I try to compile the examples "helloworld.grpc.pb.h:57:45: error: ‘grpc::ClientContext’ has not been declared"

Tags: grpc

I am trying to build the grpc-1.26.0/examples/cpp/load_balancing binaries, I have installed the gRPC with

```
cmake   -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release   -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/grpc   -DgRPC_INSTALL=ON   -DgRPC_BUILD_TESTS=OFF   -DgRPC_ABSL_PROVIDER=package   -DgRPC_CARES_PROVIDER=package   -DgRPC_PROTOBUF_PROVIDER=package   -DgRPC_SSL_PROVIDER=package   -DgRPC_ZLIB_PROVIDER=package   ../..
```

and First it does not install the -DgRPC_ABSL_PROVIDER and warns me (DO I need it?? and how do I install it?)

and Second when I run the make I get the following error

```
# make
g++ -std=c++11 `pkg-config --cflags protobuf grpc`  -c -o helloworld.grpc.pb.o helloworld.grpc.pb.cc
In file included from helloworld.grpc.pb.cc:6:0:
helloworld.grpc.pb.h:57:45: error: ‘grpc::ClientContext’ has not been declared
     virtual ::grpc::Status SayHello(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const ::helloworld::HelloRequest& request, ::helloworld::HelloReply* response) = 0;
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from helloworld.grpc.pb.cc:6:0:
helloworld.grpc.pb.h:58:115: error: ‘grpc::ClientContext’ has not been declared
 rpc::ClientAsyncResponseReaderInterface< ::helloworld::HelloReply>> AsyncSayHello(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const ::helloworld::HelloRequest& request, ::grpc::CompletionQueue* cq) {
                                                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
helloworld.grpc.pb.h:61:122: error: ‘grpc::ClientContext’ has not been declared
 ientAsyncResponseReaderInterface< ::helloworld::HelloReply>> PrepareAsyncSayHello(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const ::helloworld::HelloRequest& request, ::grpc::CompletionQueue* cq) {
                                                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
helloworld.grpc.pb.h:68:37: error: ‘grpc::ClientContext’ has not been declared
       virtual void SayHello(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const ::helloworld::HelloRequest* request, ::helloworld::HelloReply* response, std::function<void(::grpc::Status)>) = 0;
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
helloworld.grpc.pb.h:69:37: error: ‘grpc::ClientContext’ has not been declared
       virtual void SayHello(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const ::grpc::ByteBuffer* request, ::helloworld::HelloReply* response, std::function<void(::grpc::Status)>) = 0;
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
helloworld.grpc.pb.h:73:109: error: ‘AsyncSayHelloRaw’ declared as a ‘virtual’ field
 ::ClientAsyncResponseReaderInterface< ::helloworld::HelloReply>* AsyncSayHelloRaw(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const ::helloworld::HelloRequest& request, ::grpc::CompletionQueue* cq) = 0;
                                                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
helloworld.grpc.pb.h:73:84: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
     virtual ::grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReaderInterface< ::helloworld::HelloReply>* AsyncSayHelloRaw(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const ::helloworld::HelloRequest& request, ::grpc::CompletionQueue* cq) = 0;
                                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
helloworld.grpc.pb.h:73:122: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
 ResponseReaderInterface< ::helloworld::HelloReply>* AsyncSayHelloRaw(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const ::helloworld::HelloRequest& request, ::grpc::CompletionQueue* cq) = 0;
                                                                                           ^
helloworld.grpc.pb.h:74:116: error: ‘PrepareAsyncSayHelloRaw’ declared as a ‘virtual’ field
 tAsyncResponseReaderInterface< ::helloworld::HelloReply>* PrepareAsyncSayHelloRaw(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const ::helloworld::HelloRequest& request, ::grpc::CompletionQueue* cq) = 0;
                                                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
helloworld.grpc.pb.h:74:84: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
     virtual ::grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReaderInterface< ::helloworld::HelloReply>* PrepareAsyncSayHelloRaw(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const ::helloworld::HelloRequest& request, ::grpc::CompletionQueue* cq) = 0;
                                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This is just the tip of the errors I am getting......

The generated helloworld.grpc.pb.h is as follows:

```
// Generated by the gRPC C++ plugin.
// If you make any local change, they will be lost.
// source: helloworld.proto
// Original file comments:
// Copyright 2015 gRPC authors.
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.
//
#ifndef GRPC_helloworld_2eproto__INCLUDED
#define GRPC_helloworld_2eproto__INCLUDED

#include "helloworld.pb.h"

#include <functional>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/async_generic_service.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/async_stream.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/async_unary_call.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/client_callback.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/method_handler_impl.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/proto_utils.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/rpc_method.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/server_callback.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/service_type.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/status.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/stub_options.h>
#include <grpcpp/impl/codegen/sync_stream.h>

namespace grpc {
class CompletionQueue;
class Channel;
class ServerCompletionQueue;
class ServerContext;
}  // namespace grpc

namespace helloworld {

// The greeting service definition.
class Greeter final {
 public:
  static constexpr char const* service_full_name() {
    return "helloworld.Greeter";
  }
  class StubInterface {
   public:
    virtual ~StubInterface() {}
    // Sends a greeting
    virtual ::grpc::Status SayHello(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const ::helloworld::HelloRequest& request, ::helloworld::HelloReply* response) = 0;
    std::unique_ptr< ::grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReaderInterface< ::helloworld::HelloReply>> AsyncSayHello(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const ::helloworld::HelloRequest& request, ::grpc::CompletionQueue* cq) {
      return std::unique_ptr< ::grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReaderInterface< ::helloworld::HelloReply>>(AsyncSayHelloRaw(context, request, cq));
    }
    std::unique_ptr< ::grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReaderInterface< ::helloworld::HelloReply>> PrepareAsyncSayHello(::grpc::ClientContext* context, const ::helloworld::HelloRequest& request, ::grpc::CompletionQueue* cq) {
      return std::unique_ptr< ::grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReaderInterface< ::helloworld::HelloReply>>(PrepareAsyncSayHelloRaw(context, request, cq));
    }
```

I am not sure as to why doesnt the grpc namespace contain all the dependencies, how to force them in the generated file? or is it that I am missing something here.

New to the gRPC realm and trying to get thing going. Any reply will be appreciated, thanks.

Syed

Comment: It doesn't seem that gRPC has been installed properly. Did you run make install after running cmake? [BUILDING](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md) manual might be helpful.

Comment: @Esun Kim, I have run install. I can see the binaries and libraries in the /etc/local/grpc which is what I set as the install directory with cmake

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: I had solved these around the same time @Potion. for some reason cmake never worked for me,  I had run make, with the dependent llibraries code installed in the thirdparty folder.